# nested subquery, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to write a nested subquery where I choose 2 columns from 2 different tables which satisfies 3 conditions. I also insert the 2 columns into another table which actually takes 3 input but 3rd one is default.

I tried to use nested subquery but I get error all the time and I couldn't solve it. Is there another way that I can do it such as natural join.

```
INSERT INTO agency_response (AgencyName,RequestID) VALUES(AgencyName,RequestID)
SELECT AgencyName, RequestID
FROM ScoutingAgency, Request
WHERE AgencyName = @scouting_agency_name_input AND 
    RequestID = (SELECT RequestID, 
    FROM Request, Club
    WHERE RequestName = @request_name_input AND ClubName = @club_name_input);


CREATE TABLE ScoutingAgency(
    AgencyEmail VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
    AgencyName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    NumberOfScouts INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(AgencyName),
    FOREIGN KEY(AgencyEmail) REFERENCES User(UserEmail) ON DELETE SET NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Club(
    ClubEmail VARCHAR(64),
    ClubName VARCHAR(64),
    League VARCHAR(64),
    ClubRank INT,
    Country VARCHAR(64),
    Organization VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(ClubName),
    FOREIGN KEY(ClubEmail) REFERENCES User(UserEmail) ON DELETE SET NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Request(
    RequestID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RequestName VARCHAR(64),
    Organization VARCHAR(64),
    NumberOfScouts INT,
    PlayerPosition VARCHAR(64),
    RequestStatus VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(RequestID)
);


CREATE TABLE agency_response(
    AgencyName VARCHAR(64),
    RequestID INT,
    Answer VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT('waiting for response'),
    PRIMARY KEY(AgencyName,RequestID),
    FOREIGN KEY(AgencyName) REFERENCES ScoutingAgency(AgencyName) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(RequestID) REFERENCES Request(RequestID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AgencyName, RequestID FROM ScoutingAgency, Request WHERE ' at line 2

Comment: You either use `VALUES` or `SELECT`, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the data to insert from a `SELECT` subquery, you don't use the `VALUES` clause. `VALUES` is used when you want to specify the data with simple expressions rather than using a `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO agency_response (AgencyName,RequestID)
SELECT AgencyName, RequestID
FROM ScoutingAgency, Request
WHERE AgencyName = @scouting_agency_name_input AND 
    RequestID = (SELECT RequestID
    FROM Request, Club
    WHERE RequestName = @request_name_input AND ClubName = @club_name_input);
```

Comment: Thank you, and I think I should "select" 2 columns if I select "from" 2 different tables. Because I also changed into this one and it gave me the same error until delete things about Club table in the second sub-query. I think ıt doesn't accept selecting RequestID from Request and Club tables.

Comment: A subquery used with `=` can only return one column. There was an extra `,` after the column name.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit baffled by what you want to do.  From what I can tell, you are being passed in the agency name and you just need to look up the `RequestID`.  That would be:

```
CREATE TABLE agency_response (AgencyName, RequestID)
    SELECT @scouting_agency_name_input, r.RequestID
    FROM Request r
    WHERE r.RequestName = @request_name_input;
```

I don't see what a "nested subquery" has to do with this problem.

Comment: RequestName is not unique all the time if I do this doesn't it add various requestID's with same RequestName input. And I need "Answer" in agency_response, if I create table like this I will lose "Answer" am I right?

Comment: @Utku . . . There is no "answer" in your question.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a NEW question.  If you are concerned about duplicates, you can use `select distinct` or `group by`.  That doesn't seem to be an issue in your question.